# function count_numbers that accepts a sorted list of unique integers

Tags: python-3.x, bisect

Implement function count_numbers that accepts a sorted list of unique integers and, efficiently with respect to time used, counts the number of list elements that are less than the parameter less_than.

For example, count_numbers([1, 3, 5, 7], 4) should return 2 because there are two list elements less than 4.

```
**def count_numbers(sorted_list, less_than):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sorted_list = [1, 3, 5, 7]
    print(count_numbers(sorted_list, 4)) # should print 2**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bisect import bisect_left
def count_numbers(sorted_list, less_than):
    i = bisect_left(sorted_list, less_than)
    return i
        
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sorted_list = [1, 3, 5, 7]
    print(count_numbers(sorted_list, 0))
```